# PHP AJAX handler file organization

Tags: php, jquery

I am currently learning jQuery and AJAX and was wondering about best practices for organization of the server-side scripts that handle the AJAX calls.  Should I have a handler.php file which then routes the AJAX calls to other functions in different files? Or do you just put everything in one file and use a big switch{}?  The system will likely expand in the future and I want to organize it in a way that scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A routing file is the way to go, not just for your AJAX requests but for all actions that can be invoked within your system by a web request. You should be placing related actions into a single controller file, and then loading/invoking the correct file/method from your public-facing router.

A good [framework](http://phpframeworks.com), which you absolutely should be using, will do this for you.

Comment: @meager So, should I pass a function name in the AJAX call, which the handler script will use to route it to the correct file/function?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I place the each `AJAX` call in a function. I name the functions depending on what data I want to retrieve, `getUsers(), getComments()` etc. Than I call the functions when I need to in `JS`.

On the PHP side, I use different scripts for each database request. `getUsers.php` etc...